# Como faço para enviar uma lista como data source para um sub relatório e chamar esse sub relatório no meu relatório principal

Tags: java, lista, jasper-reports

Bom dia pessoal, estou com um pequeno problema. Estou tentando passar uma `lista` como `data source` para o meu sub relatório. Eu já tenho o relatório principal que também é preenchido por uma lista. Minha dúvida é a seguinte, como faço para passar uma `lista` como `data source` para meu sub relatório e em seguida chamar esse sub relatório dentro de meu relatório principal?

Esse é o meu método que gera o relatório e exporta em pdf para um diretório:

```
public boolean gerarRelatorio(List list, int numeroRelatorio, String nomePrestador, String dataSistema) {
        JasperReport report = null;
        InputStream image = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/br/com/xml/relatorio/LOGO.png");
        filtro.put("Image", image);
        try {
            InputStream inputStreamReal = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/br/com/xml/relatorio/Relatorio2.jrxml");
            report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(inputStreamReal);
        } catch (JRException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(frmPegaXml.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro ao pegar arquivos!", "ERRO!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
        try {

            JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, filtro, new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(list));
            JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(print,
                    "C:/Demonstrativos/" + dataSistema + "/" + nomePrestador + "_" + dataSistema + "_" + numeroRelatorio + ".pdf");

            /*Variaveis necessarias para salvar o Arquivo no Banco de dados*/
            caminho1 = "C:/Demonstrativos/" + dataSistema + "/";
            ext = ".zip";
            nomeArquivo1 = nomePrestador + "_" + dataSistema + "_" + numeroRelatorio;
            caminhoCompleto = caminho1 + nomeArquivo1 + ".pdf";

            codAP = Long.parseLong(codArquivoPrestador);
            relatoriosGerados = numeroRelatorio + 1;
            return true;
            /*Variaveis necessarias para salvar o Arquivo  no Banco de dados*/
        } catch (JRException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(frmPegaXml.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro ao Gerar relatório, verifique se nenhum arquivo está aberto ou se o nome está correto!\n" + ex, "ERRO!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Estou usando JasperSoft Studio, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá, não é tão complicado. 
Para a lista você cria um parâmetro em código e cria um pra mandar o diretório do seu sub-relatório.
Assim, na hora que você por seu sub-relatório no relatório principal e for configurá-lo no campo "Expression"(campo que diz onde está/qual o sub-relatório), você passa o parâmetro para dizer onde esta o sub-relatório, no campo "Data Source Expression" você manda sua lista da seguinte maneira:
"new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(parametroDaLista)".
Porém, você vai ter que definir o parâmetro no seu relatório principal, tanto para lista quanto para o diretório, lembrando que o parâmetro tem que ser idêntico ao que você criou em código!
Espero ter ajudado, dúvida é só chamar!
Abraço!

Comment: A resposta do colega acima está correta, é a melhor forma de se fazer, só complemento dizendo que não precisa necessariamente ser um parâmetro, você pode também passar um campo do seu data source principal, desde que este seja uma lista.